# Parsing XML file using explode and to get output in a single array

Tags: php, xml, html, xml-parsing, xhtml

I have an XML file [xml](http://pastebin.com/suhxzFhC)
I am parsing the file with the code  -

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file('info.xml');

foreach($xml->testcase as $var){

    $var=explode('/',$var->script);

    $module =array($var[2]);

    $testName = array (end($var));

    print_r($module); 

    print_r($testName); 
    }

?>
```

With this code my output looks like [output](http://pastebin.com/myPZABq2)

But my output should be like two arrays `(name say module and testName)` containing the  `$var[2]` and `end($var)`

Comment: you mean you want a associative array?

Comment: Ajay - I mean I want something like  module = (802dot1xRadAccAVPClntStatIp.tcl, 802dot1xBasicUserMode.tcl,  802dot1xRadiusAccEnableDisable.tcl )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this format

```
<?php
    $xml=simplexml_load_file('info.xml');
    foreach($xml->testcase as $var){

        $var=explode('/',$var->script);

        $module[] =$var[2];

        $testName[] = end($var);


        }
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($module);
        echo implode(',',$module);

        print_r($testName);

        echo implode(',',$testName);

        exit;
    ?>
```

Create Dropdown

```
<select name="sample">
        <?php       
        foreach($module as $mod)
        {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $mod;?>"><?php echo $mod;?></option>
            <?php
        }       
        ?>
        </select>
```

Second Alternative

```
<select name="sample">
        <?php
        $i=1;
        foreach($module as $mod)
        {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $mod;?>"><?php echo $testName[$i];?></option>
            <?php
            $i++;
        }



    ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: but i have one doubt - I am suppose to send array $module and $testName to a html page to get dropdown list. As there is no name for the array how can i refer to it ?

Comment: uumm.. with the values of $module and $testname I want to create a dropdown list. SO for that I need to send these value to html script. So for sending the values I need to refer these.. so how can I do that ?

Comment: your answer is coreect , the only change is that $i++ will be inside the foreach loop .
Edit your answer so that I can accept is :D

Comment: Oh i forgot it @Pooja. Now i edit my question. if you have any query's share with me

Comment: with the output like [output](http://pastebin.com/jbYuYTEZ)

why array_unique is not working ?

For the above output if I use $modules[] = array_unique($module);
I get output like [output2](http://pastebin.com/aXc2bZwh)
why i am not getting a single array of unique values ?

Comment: try this $modules = array_unique($module); and print_r($modules)

Comment: i tried this  .. the problem here is with the index.. its like 

Array
(
    [0] => networkSecurity
    [23] => mobilityExamples
    [27] => hostAgentFeatures
    [39] => sdnSTC
)

why its not like -

Array
(
    [0] => networkSecurity
    [1] => mobilityExamples
    [2] => hostAgentFeatures
    [3] => sdnSTC
)

Comment: foreach ($array as $newarr) { $newarrcreation[]=$newarr;} print_r($newarrcreation);

Comment: @Pooja  just create a form before select box and you get the selected value in next page